# C++ pipe and fork

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, fork, dup

I'm working on a sample program to learn how pipes and forking works. In my very basic implementation, in my child process, i closed 0 and duplicated the read end of the pipe so that file descriptor 0 is now the read end of my pipe.

From my parent process, I write out a string, and in my child process, I read the string using cin as cin essentially is my read end of the pipe and what I observe is the complete string does not print out and I can't seem to understand why!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define TEST_STRING "Hello, Pipe!"
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);

  pid_t pid;
  if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    //Child
    close(0);
    close(fd[1]);
    int myCin = dup(fd[0]);
    char buf[sizeof(TEST_STRING)];

    // int x;
    // std::cin >> x;
    // std::cout << x << std::endl;
    // read(myCin, buf, sizeof(TEST_STRING));
    std::cin >> buf;

    std::cout << buf << std::endl;

  }
  else {
    //parent
    write(fd[1], TEST_STRING, sizeof(TEST_STRING));
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here's my strace as well:

```
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7fd895adaa10) = 1904
strace: Process 1904 attached
[pid  1903] write(4, "Hello, Pipe!\0", 13) = 13
[pid  1903] close(4)                    = 0
[pid  1903] wait4(1904,  <unfinished ...>
[pid  1904] close(0)                    = 0
[pid  1904] close(4)                    = 0
[pid  1904] dup(3)                      = 0
[pid  1904] fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
[pid  1904] read(0, "Hello, Pipe!\0", 4096) = 13
[pid  1904] fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
[pid  1904] write(1, "Hello,\n", 7)     = 7
[pid  1904] read(0, "", 4096)           = 0
[pid  1904] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid  1904] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: using std::cin.getline(buf, sizeof(buf));  instead of  std::cin >> buf; can get you the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you read from `cin` that way it will discard leading whitespace and then *stop at the next whitespace character*.  So that's why it only returned what it did.  Try `std:getline`.

You shouldn't count on `dup()` choosing FD 0 for you. Use `dup2()` so you can specify what descriptor to use.

I also doubt changing the FD from under cin is safe.  You could get buffered data from before the FD was duped.

Comment: plus 1 for the remark about changing FD from under cin