# C++ cin cout to another exe

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

I have 2 different executables which use traditional cin/cout to interact with the user.

Lets imagine it is a program that inputs some numbers and outputs the result.

Now I want to write a driving program in C++ that calls these executables and provides inputs to them (**"cin>>"**'s a value) and also gets the result of their **cout**.

I tried using `system()` that makes a command line call that starts the executable. But I am not able to provide a further input(in some cases inputs) to that. Any idea how to do that?

Unfortunately I can't switch the program to take command line arguments.

Comment: Not sure what is your problem, but looks like you need jus redirect stdout and stdin and you done. You do not need write any program. Just do: `yourProgram.exe <input.txt >output.txt` or `yourProgram1.exe <input.txt | yourProgram2.exe >output.txt`.

Comment: Use fork, exec and pipes to connect the two programs.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42311299/1216776

Comment: @stark it is windows, based on `winapi` tag.

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output?redirectedfrom=MSDN) answer your question?